# How to change FAR Manager's shell?

Tags: far-manager

I want all commands run from FAR to be executed under, say, Bash. Is there a way to tell FAR to bypass all commands to something other than `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the [Comspec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMSPEC) to bash. In addition you'll want to change the arguments passed to the Comspec and for which commands the Comspec should be used.

You could change the environment variable `COMSPEC` before (or manually after) starting Far Manager to bash (`%windir%\system32\bash.exe`) or change the internal settings (stored in `%AppData%\Roaming\Far Manager\Profile\generalconfig.db`).

You can change the settings by executing **`far:config`** in the Far Manager prompt. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to start filtering by name and then type **`comspec`**.

**Default comspec** options:

```
  System.Executor.Comspec                   │string │%COMSPEC%
  System.Executor.ComspecArguments          │string │/S /C "{0}"
  System.Executor.ComspecCondition          │string │
```

You can **change them to**:

```
* System.Executor.Comspec                   │string │C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe
* System.Executor.ComspecArguments          │string │"{0}"
* System.Executor.ComspecCondition          │string │.*
```

If you don't change the `ComspecCondition` only some commands will be passed as arguments to `bash`. For example if you execute `notepad` with an empty `ComspecCondition` (default value) notepad will be started normally.

To **reset a value** to its initial condition, edit the value and click on the `Reset` button.

More details about how this settings are used can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/FarGroup/FarManager/blob/master/far/execute.cpp).