# How do I run all commands via Comspec?

Tags: far-manager

I've set up `System.Executor.Comspec` and the `Arguments` to point elsewhere. However, FAR still runs programs directly if it finds them on the PATH. I know there's `System.Executor.ExcludeCmds`, but it wants every command to be specified individually.  Is there a way to tell FAR "whatever the command, always run it via Comspec"? (except `far:config` of course :)

Comment: The solution was mentioned in the answer https://superuser.com/questions/1524790/how-to-change-far-managers-shell and the ".*" value was in the screenshot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `System.Executor.ComspecCondition` to `.*`.